# Was the question in my e-mail unclear?

Tags: communication, email

Just a sanity check here if you don't mind. I had what I thought was a simple question. "Do we need to open these additional ports on the firewall for some servers". I didn't quite get the guys response. And I wanted to see if I'm at fault for not understanding.

My exact question was this:

> "Hi David,
>
> I have a question about SCOM monitoring. I found this list of ports
>   in the wiki as being important to SCOM:
>
> 5723/tcp, 1024-5000/tcp, 49152-65535/tcp, 135/tcp, 445/tcp,
>   137-139/udp
>
> But earlier you said that only 5723 is important. I just wanted to
>   check that we don’t need these other ports as well."

And this is the response I get back from David:

> "Hi Tim,
>
> Original SCOM agents were installed by Enterprise Management Team and
>   these Ports listed were necessary for installing agent from SCOM
>   Operation Manager Console.
>
> The SCOM Agent install process has been transition as operational and
>   is now handle by theTech Lifecycle Management Team.
>
> Please let me know if you have any further questions.
>
> Thanks"

I just want to know if it's me who's not getting the answer. Or if he's not explaining correctly or even being slightly rude in this response. I have absolutely no familiarity with MS SCOM, and I get the impression that he assumes that I should know the product as well as he does.

Or perhaps my question was judged as rude, since I found different information in the wiki and I wanted to confirm?

Comment: If the person is in the same office it would be better to walk over to his desk  and talk to him

Comment: I see no question, at all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about MS SCOM, not a question about the workplace.  You could ask a question about resolving communication issues among coworkers, but this doesn't seem to be that question.

Comment: "and I get the impression that he assumes that I should know the product as well as he does."  It serves as a reminder that you can't make everybody happy all the time.  In my experience if you assume ignorance you're just as likely to piss people off.

Comment: I see no question either, but there are 3 answers anyway. Oh dear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Original SCOM agents were installed by Enterprise Management Team 
and these Ports listed were necessary for installing agent from SCOM Operation 
Manager Console
```

Looks like the ports are required for the install by the above team but may no longer be necessary now that the install is done. He directed you to the team handling the operations as this is likely the install team.

Answer (score 4):

> The SCOM Agent install process has been transition as operational and is now handle by KTech Lifecycle Management Team.

That's the people you need to redirect your question to - they are responsible for maintenance and configuration.

> Please let me know if you have any further questions.

If you don't know how to contact the team, then David is the person to ask for the contact info.

If they don't know which ports are important and which are not, ask them what SCOM ports they are leaving open right now. When they get back to you with a list of SCOM open ports, ask them to justify/explain why they decided to leave the non 5723/tcp ports open.

You have the official authority to ask, right? If not, you are butting into something that's none of your concern. If you have the official authority to ask, frame your question as a due diligence question, which you are asking for the sake of network security. Don't tell them that the only thing you know about SCOM is a couple of paragraphs in a wiki - they don't have to know that, they don't need to know that.

Answer (score 3):

> I found this list of ports in the wiki as being important

You asked if the ports were "important".  You did NOT ask, directly, if they should be closed at the present time.  Asking if something is "important" may at times be soliciting a ***subjective*** answer, and not an ***objective*** answer.  I  think you should just respond with:

```
David: please confirm that it's okay to open these ports now.
```

The response you should receive from this is either YES, or NO.

Comment: It appears, to me at least, that David is also saying the KTech team is in charge of this now, so ask them.

Comment: @LaconicDroid Not for certain.  In that statement he's referring to the installation process, and not necessarily the ports on the device(s) OP is referring to.

Comment: OP wants to OPEN the ports, which would be a little bigger pill to swallow: "Do we need to open these additional ports on the firewall for some servers"

Comment: Unless something is broken the answer will usually default to "No"